# Link Paypal subscription and it's refund

Tags: paypal

I'm not a developer, but a data analyst. Please excuse my lack of knowledge of API.

I have 3 tables from Paypal API:

- subscriptions
- refunds
- disputes

There is no shared key/column that I can associate with the original subscription to refund or dispute. It looks like we are pulling all the information available.

Is it really not possible to link a refund/dispute back to the parent subscription? Or have we missed something?

Comment: It's not possible for us to verify your claim that you "*are pulling all the information available*", nor if you have "*missed something*" without more details on *what* fields you're storing, when, and from where (at the bare minimum). [ask]

Comment: `I have 3 tables from Paypal API`, that specifies either that the data you are **provided** has 3 tables **or** that there are endpoints of PayPal API that are mirrored 1:1 into some table. If it's the first, without knowing the table structure it's complicated to answer correctly, so it's rather guessing.

If it's the latter, provide the endpoints, then it'll be possible to cross-reference the parts or a subject expert will be able to answer properly.

Answer (score 0):

Refunds should reference the parent transaction at the least, and parent transactions should reference the subscription ID.  If you don't have this information available, it's because you haven't stored it from the responses you receive from PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about these tables - and simply query the live API instead.
This would be the full data-set, until today, which has all the fields.